# How to cover Try Catch in test classes

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a trigger named  DueDiligenceListHandler on our Stage instance which according to Developer Console has lines within a catch block which I can't seem to cover using my test class named TestDueDiligenceListHandler  I specifically tried to test the exception

Is this one of those situations? If not, how can I move forward and get the lines within my catch block for this trigger covered by my test class method?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special credits to @sfdcfox for this one.

To get the catch block to execute, an exception would need to originate from the try block of code in the trigger. If your trigger was doing an update, some validation elsewhere might result in a DMLException being thrown.

The important thing about your test methods is that they verify your code works correctly. Unless you have a way of crafting a record that will fail (1st suggestion above), the only other method-- which is strongly not recommended-- would be to write a exception built into the actual code you're testing. This involves using Test.isRunningTest to set up an arbitrary failure.

[Test Code coverage catch block](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16727/test-code-coverage-catch-block)

Please note that Not all code that is written can be covered. This is a fact of salesforce.com development. There is a reason why the deployment rule is 75% coverage, and not 100% coverage.