# how to cover this catch in my batch?

Tags: apex, lightning, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

```
for (APC_I_c rAPC : scope) {
        rAPC.Error__c = null;
        rAPC.Type_of_Error__c = null;
        rAPC.Status__c = 'Processed';
        if(rAPC.APC_ID_Account_RCS__c != null){
                 
            try{
                Account acc =  new Account();
                acc.APC_Id__c = rAPC.APC_ID_Account_RCS__c;           
                acc.Name = rAPC.Account_Name__c;
                lstaccAPC.add(acc);
                
            }catch(Exception exc){
                APC_I_Batch_Helper.processError(rAPC,exc.getMessage());
```

Comment: i want to test it but the test doesn't cover that catch

Comment: It looks quite possibly to be a situation where you are catching errors which cannot occur.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the try-catch block. It is not possible to have an exception here. Generally speaking, if you're having problems trying to cover a try-catch block, it is either untestable, or unnecessary. It's important to learn when exceptions can occur in order to catch them effectively. Also see [Pokemon Catch - Generic Exception Handling In Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/136920/2984) and [Test Code coverage catch block](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/16727/2984), as well as [Can batchable custom iterables support null values?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47856/2984), in which I discover that `scope` will never contain null values.